# What is the / symbol called?

Tags: punctuation

What is the "/" symbol called? Being a techie, I have heard it called the "forward slash" in the context of unix directories. However, I am now doing technical writing and need to know the actual name.

Comment: From the first sentence of the [Wikipedia entry on "Slash (punctuation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation))": "The **slash** (/), also known as a **stroke** and by the technical term **solidus**, is a sign used as a punctuation mark and for various other purposes. It is often called a **forward slash**, a retronym used to distinguish it from the backslash (\\). It has many [other names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation)#Alternative_names)."

Comment: other names ... Maybe I will start calling it "virgula suspensiva"...

Comment: I would like to point out that **solidus** also can refer to a separate piece of punctuation that is similar to a more horizontal version of a "/".

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the use, it can also be called a “virgule.” I’ve seen it called this when used to indicate to the reader that a choice between the words it separates is necessary. (e.g., in “Each person must bring her/his own dictionary,” the reader needs to choose either “her” or “his” so that the sentence adheres to  grammatical/syntactical rules about pronoun number-agreement. Usually voiced as “or” when reading such a sentence aloud.)

Now that I’m thinking about this, it seems that the answer to your question is highly context-dependent. I mean, I’ve also seen “/” used as a shorthand for the shilling mark. Or to represent line breaks in poetry when quoting them on a single, wrapped line (e.g. "The woods are lovely, dark and deep, / But I have promises to keep, / And miles to go before I sleep, / And miles to go before I sleep.”)

We'd need to know what you’re using the “/” for to give you the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's a *forward slash*, or simply *slash*, if you don't need to distinguish it from the *backward slash* ('\'), the Windows directory separator.

It's also called *stroke*, *oblique*, or **solidus**, but as a software/techie guy myself I've personally only encountered **slash** or **forward slash**.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_%28punctuation%29)

*Oblique* is British English, according to Longman.

Comment: One other term, mentioned in the Wikipedia article, is *virgule.*